# mySQL two counts in one query

Tags: mysql

I want to count the total number of accidents per year and the amount of car accidents happening per year separately. My code however, it seems to only count the total number of accidents.

So far my code is:

```
Select Year, Count(*) AS 'Total', Count(*) AS 'Car' 
FROM ACCIDENTS 
WHERE Car = 1 
GROUP BY Year, Car 
Order BY Year ASC;
```

Table should be something like this:

```
Year |  Accidents | Car
1990      500        25
1991      521        18
```

**Structure of table:**

[image]

I would count the years for the total amount of accidents and then the types of accidents would have boolean values to represent whether it was that type of accident.

Comment: what is the full structure of this table?

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear. I added a the structure of the table if that helps.

Comment: It might be worth noting that 2 simple queries might be faster for MySQL than 1 complex query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query

```
Select Year, Count(*) AS 'Total', count(case when car =1 then 1 else null end) FROM ACCIDENTS GROUP BY Year Order BY Year ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried to do it separately using two queries but when I did  "SELECT Car, Count(*) AS 'Car' FROM ACCIDENTS GROUP BY Car ORDER BY Car  ASC;" but  it says "ambigous column name.

Comment: @ShiroPie : Give a different name for `Count(*) as`

Comment: Thank you. I thought the names don't matter but turns out it does.